# Python and Prime Numbers

Tags: python

I know there are a bunch of topics on this, and I hate to create a new one, but none of the topics seem to fit exactly right, unless it is doing something in a more advanced way.  I am in an intro to programming class, and want (need?) to use simple commands that we've learned in the first week to do this, and I also want to have code that is "my own" and not just snag something off the internet.

I am working on two scripts (.py files) that are extremely basic.  One asks for a number and prints out whether it is a prime number or not, the other prints out all of the prime numbers up to the 1000th prime number (Which we know is 7919, because we were given a link to a list of primes to check our work).

My first script:

```
yourNumber= input('Enter a number: ')
isPrime = 0
if yourNumber == 1:
    isPrime = 1
    print(yourNumber,'is not a prime number')
else : 
    for primeCheck in range (int(2), int(yourNumber)):
        if int(yourNumber)%int(primeCheck) == 0:
            isPrime = 1
            break
        else:
            isPrime = 0
    if isPrime == 0:
        print(yourNumber,'is a prime number')
    else:
        print(yourNumber,'is not a prime number')
```

This one seems to work for any number except 0 and 1.  I don't know what I am doing wrong.

---

My second script:

```
numberPrimes = 0
startNumber = 0
currentNumber = startNumber
isPrime = 0
while numberPrimes < 1000:
    if currentNumber == 1:
        currentNumber = currentNumber + 1
    else:
        for primeCheck in range (int(2), int(currentNumber)):
            if int(currentNumber)%primeCheck == 0:
                isPrime = 1
                break
            else:
                isPrime = 0
        if isPrime == 0:
            print(currentNumber, 'is prime')
            numberPrimes = numberPrimes + 1
            currentNumber == currentNumber + 1
        else:
            currentNumber == currentNumber + 1
```

This one basically spits out "0 is prime" one thousand times.  Somehow the currentNumber is not going up or something.  I'm not sure.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding where you typoed = as ==

Comment: `int(2)` is irrelevant - `2` is already an integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Program**

```
yourNumber= input('Enter a number: ')
isPrime = 0
if yourNumber == 1:
    isPrime = 1
    print(yourNumber,'is not a prime number')
else : 
    for primeCheck in range (int(2), int(yourNumber)):
        if int(yourNumber)%int(primeCheck) == 0:
            isPrime = 1
            break
        else:
            isPrime = 0
    if isPrime == 0:
        print(yourNumber,'is a prime number')
    else:
        print(yourNumber,'is not a prime number')
```

**Suggestions:**

1. `int(2), int(yourNumber), int(primeCheck)` You dont need to convert `yourNumber` (`input` will function will do that automaticallly), `primeCheck` and `2` to `int` everytime.
2. `if yourNumber == 1:` If you want to eliminate `0` as well, `if yourNumber == 0 or  yourNumber == 1`

**Second program**

```
numberPrimes = 0
startNumber = 0
currentNumber = startNumber
isPrime = 0
while numberPrimes < 1000:
    if currentNumber == 1:
        currentNumber = currentNumber + 1
    else:
        for primeCheck in range (int(2), int(currentNumber)):
            if int(currentNumber)%primeCheck == 0:
                isPrime = 1
                break
            else:
                isPrime = 0
        if isPrime == 0:
            print(currentNumber, 'is prime')
            numberPrimes = numberPrimes + 1
            currentNumber == currentNumber + 1
        else:
            currentNumber == currentNumber + 1
```

**Suggestions**

1. Same as in the first program's first suggestion.
2. `currentNumber == currentNumber + 1` is not assigning incremented value back to `currentNumber` but it is comparing. So, the actual way to do this is, `currentNumber = currentNumber + 1`

Comment: First script- Actually, I had to convert it because if I just have "yourNumber" it gives an error about an "str".  I had to specify it as an integer type for it to even do ANYTHING (other than give me errors)

Comment: @Ernesto Are you sure? Which line gave that error?

Comment: Second script - Wow, I can't believe I did that.  I know the difference between assigning a value and comparing a value, but somehow I doubled the equal sign >.<  You can see that the FIRST time I did it, I had it correct, but when I typed it the next two times, I added an extra one (I actually copy and pasted it from the line right above when i was doing the third one, so that's how it happened twice instead of just once.)

Comment: Give me one second to change it back and I will tell you.

Comment: Enter a number: 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Programming/Documents/contents/assignments/inputprime.py", line 7, in <module>
    for primeCheck in range (2, yourNumber):
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: I guess you are using Python3.x. Anyway, you dont have to do it again and again. You can simply do `yourNumber = int(input('...'))`

Comment: I don't know, I think I am using Python 3.3, which is what was available on the Python website.  Should I be using something different?

Comment: No no. Thats perfectly fine :)

Comment: Putting the int() where I first assign it a value through the input() did work, a lot of thanks for that.  I had thought about that when I first got the str error, but I had done it wrong:  `int(yourNumber) = input('...')`  Which doesn't work.

Comment: @Ernesto You are welcome :) You can even upvote the answer if it really helps you :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/198551/235416

Comment: By the way, thank you SOOOOOOO much for the help, and for actually being there to give responses quickly, that really helped a lot.  I am actually at work right now, but I am doing this online thing and trying to do the problem sets.  Since it's online, I don't really have access to profs or TAs, so google is my friend.  But you are my BEST friend ;)

Comment: I selected it as the answer, I cannot upvote because it says I need 15 rep, and I'm probably negative right now.

Answer (score 2):

In the following two lines, taken from your example, consider the difference between `=` and `==`.

```
        numberPrimes = numberPrimes + 1
        currentNumber == currentNumber + 1
```

Each of these lines does something, but they do not do the same thing. Using what you've learned so far, determine what that something is.

Answer (score 0):

**Algorithm-wise**

0 and 1 are special cases.  They're neither prime nor composite.  Do like the mathematicians do and avoid them.  Start `currentNumber` at 2 and make your program work like that.

**Bug-wise**

`==` means 'compare'.  If the only thing on a given line is `(something) == (something else)`, that line is usually doing nothing.

**Program-wise**

You're new, so this is meant to be helpful.  When you're talking about things that should be True or False (boolean values), please use the Python keywords `True` and `False` rather than 1 and 0.  It makes your program clearer to read.

Think about your data types in this program; you're using the `int()` function a lot on things that were `int`s all along.  If you're sure it's an `int`, don't cast it, and if you're not sure, cast it before it's set.

Consider the special cases you're handling in your first program.  You first test whether the input is 1, then if not you do wheel factorization (good).  What happens if you remove that first test?  Since 2 is bigger than 1, `range` will return an empty set.

Comment: I would have thought the same thing in terms of having to set it as an int.  I didn't initially, but with the following code:yourNumber= input('Enter a number: ')
isPrime = 0
if yourNumber == 1:
    isPrime = 1
    print(yourNumber,'is not a prime number')
else : 
    for primeCheck in range (2, yourNumber):
        if yourNumber%primeCheck == 0:
            isPrime = 1
            break
        else:
            isPrime = 0
    if isPrime == 0:
        print(yourNumber,'is a prime number')
    else:
        print(yourNumber,'is not a prime number')

Comment: Ugh, the comment thing on this website sucks.  Basically if I remove the int() functions it tells me the "for primeCheck in range (2, yourNumber):
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Comment: I would guess you're using Python 3, where `input()` always returns a string (many people still use python 2).  Try using `yourNumber = int(input('Enter a number:'))`.  What I was saying is set it correctly the first time, rather than checking every time.